# Which script am I missing when trying to install framework7 custom build?

Tags: web, npm, html-framework-7

```
npm ERR! missing script: build-core:prod
```

I'm receiving the above error when trying to run the custom build for framework7 - https://framework7.io/docs/custom-build.html

I have gone through each step however I am running into this problem in cmder and I'm unsure why.

The error occurs at step 7 if this info is of any value

Any help would be appreicated.

Answer (score 0):

The error says it cannot find the script **build-core:prod**.

I could replicate this error (missing **build-core:prod**), by **NOT INSTALLING THE DEPENDENCIES** after cloning from github.

So the steps are:

### 1. Clone the Framework7 Github repository

```
git clone https://github.com/framework7io/framework7 my-app
```

- this will download the repository in a folder called my-app

### 2. Install Node.js

- that's another topic, hope you have that installed

### 3. Install Gulp

```
npm install --global gulp
```

- if you don't have that

### 4. Install dependencies

```
cd my-app

npm install
```

- be sure that you are in the root of my-app (the directory you just created for the cloned repository)
- this installs all the dependencies that Framework7 Custom Build needs

### 5. Duplicate my-app/scripts/build-config.js

- and rename the duplicate to my-app/scripts/**my-config.js**

### 6. Open my-config.js and edit it as you need

### 7. Go to my-app folder (the root)

- and run

  npm run build-core:prod -- --config scripts/my-config.js --output path/to/output/folder
- path/to/output/folder is a path to the folder where you want the customised files to be, it can be (for example) f7-my-custom-build

### 8. The custom build is ready,

- hopefully you can work with it now. :)

Comment: i followed this and it still didn't work, it keeps returning the same error

Comment: Hmmm... still not working? Did the error message change?